# unable to display Group in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to display grid in group as per the guide line, but it is unable to load data in jqGrid.

Can anybody help me out?

```
$("#Addresses").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'xmlstring',
    datastr: xmlString.XmlToString(),
    mtype: 'POST',
    beforeRequest: function () {
        //alert('beforeRequest');
    },
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $(this).HideBusy();
        //   alert(status);
        //     alert(error);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var Address = $("#Addresses").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'Address');
        SelectedAddresses.find("CRD1>row").each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).find('Address').text() == Address) {
                var v1 = $(this).XmlToString();
                var v2 = '<CRD1>' + v1 + '</CRD1>';
                $(this).SetValuesToControl("BusinessPartner #uxAddresses", $($.parseXML(v2)));
            }
        });
    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        var top_rowid = $('#Addresses tr:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
        $("#Addresses").setSelection(top_rowid, true);
        $(this).HideBusy();
    },
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    xmlReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "CRD1", row: 'row' },
    colNames: ['Address', 'AdresType'],
    colModel: [
                        { name: 'Address', key: true, index: 'Address asc', hidden: false },
                        { name: 'AdresType', index: 'AdresType', sortable: false, align: "left" }
           ],
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    height: 150,
    width: 110,
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: 'AdresType',
        groupColumnShow: false
    },
    scrollOffset: 0
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchOnEnter: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: false });
```

I saw this [link](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), I have notice that in the groupField there is two square bracket([]) which represent array, I am assuming that it is use for multiple groups.

If I specify FieldName in square brack (ex: groupField: ['AdresType']), It throws me jqGrid error.

Error :
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

Sample Data :

```
<CRD1>
<row>
    <Address>HeadOffice</Address>
    <CardCode>A0002</CardCode>
    <City nil="true"/>
    <County nil="true"/>
    <Building/>
    <AdresType>B</AdresType>
</row>
<row>
    <Address>SiteOffice</Address>
    <CardCode>A0002</CardCode>
    <City nil="true"/>
    <County nil="true"/>
    <Building/>
    <AdresType>B</AdresType>
</row>
    <row>
    <Address>PuneOffice</Address>
    <CardCode>A0002</CardCode>
    <City nil="true"/>
    <County nil="true"/>
    <Building/>
    <AdresType>S</AdresType>
</row>
```

Comment: The code which you included contains a lot of contradiction. For example you use `datatype: 'xmlstring'` and `datastr: xmlString.XmlToString()` which means that you use input data **previously loaded** in your JavaScript program, but you use `mtype: 'POST'`, `loadError, ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }` which works only with remote data like `datatype: "xml"` moreover `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` would be wrong at all for XML data. You should remove `index` properties from `colModel`.

Comment: If you have problem with *loading of data* it would be helpful it you append the text of your question with the test data which can be used to reproduces the problem. Moreover you should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in case of any error and post the version of jqGrid which you use and **the line number in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`** where the error take place.

Comment: Well, datatype is xmlstring and xmlString is jquery xml object, so I have convert jquery xml object to xml string. you ask me to remove index, I don't understand it well.

Comment: Same code works for me if I remove groupingview option... I don't understand what's the problem with group.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful in the type of data used in `groupingView`. [The documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#grid_options) contains the table with `Property`, `Type`, `Description` and `Default` columns. The `Type` column of both `groupField` and `groupColumnShow` contains `array`. So the correct will be the usage of

```
groupingView: {
    groupField: ['AdresType'],
    groupColumnShow: [false]
}
```

instead of

```
groupingView: {
    groupField: 'AdresType',
    groupColumnShow: false
}
```

**UPDATED**: There are one more problem: there is a bug in jqGrid. [The lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L1374-L1377)

```
if(!locdata) {
    self.jqGrid('groupingRender',grpdata,ts.p.colModel.length, ts.p.page, rn);
}
grpdata = null;
```

should be changed to

```
if(!locdata) {
    self.jqGrid('groupingRender',grpdata,ts.p.colModel.length, ts.p.page, rn);
    grpdata = null;
}
```

The bug is already fixed in the main code of jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commit/bcb84951baa3c5fa5e41aabe5076bdcec2815f7b)) on Mar 3 2014, but no new release of jqGrid is published in the time. I hope that Tony will release new version very soon.

So you can make the corresponding modification in your copy of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. Alternatively you can use any other datatype excepting `datatype: 'xmlstring'`.

Comment: As you said, after making the changes it throws me error "Error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined"

Comment: @Manish: See **UPDATED** part of jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I am new to all these things, I saw the source code but I don't know how to use it, I found there are lot of js files like base,common,custom,formatter,pivot,subgrid. I don't know how to compile this in one js. can you please guide me.

Comment: @Manish: As I wrote you have two options: the first one to open `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` in any text editor and to move the line 1377 (with `grpdata = null;`) one live above (place it inside of `if`). To create minimized version you can download `AjaxMin.exe` for example from http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/ and execute `AjaxMin.exe -enc:in utf-8 -clobber:true jquery.jqGrid.src.js -o jquery.jqGrid.min.js -map:v3 jquery.jqGrid.min.map`. You can minimize `grid.locale-en.js` or `ui.jqgrid.css` too. You suould only use additional option `-enc:out utf-8` for `locale-XX` files.

Comment: @Manish: to minimize the current code from github you should use [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/downloads) or [ant](https://ant.apache.org/). You should choose the way if you familiar with the tools. If you would choose the way I would recommend you to apply changes from my pending request https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/654 additionally.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for your support, I have download jqGrid src from https://code.google.com/p/apollo/source/browse/trunk/apollo-ws/web-client/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js?r=149 location and use it directly on my web application. I assume that changes that you recommended is already there. When I run the project it gives me error "Unable to get property 'msie'....", After googling, i found that we need use migrate plugin also. I have use <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script> to make it work. Now Grouping view is working. Please let me know if any changes are required.

Comment: @Manish: You should **always** get sources from original web site and to use the last version. You can download jqGrid from [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). The required changes I describe in my answer. If you get `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` 4.6.0 then you should go to the line number 1377.